# Refreshing Power BI with Access as Database

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerbi

My Team is working with Power BI, where we use a Report Server and the Cloud. For one Power Bi file, we connected some Excel Sheets and a Access File. Everything is fine. The upload on every Server is working. Nonetheless, if we try to refresh the Power BI file there is a certain error.
If we try to refresh the PowerBI File in the report server the error is:

```
SessionID : a63570ad-2411-4b53-b9ce-6a969cb00c97
[0] -1055784932 : DataFormat.Error: Unspecified error. Project_Acquisition_Overview_AE-BE_current.accdb. ;Unspecified error. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[1] -1055129594 : The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
[2] -1055784932 : The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
```

If we try to refresh the PowerBi file via the Cloud the error is following:

```
Fehler bei der Datenquelle{"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Microsoft Access: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine OLEDB provider may be required to read 'Project_Acquisition_Overview_AE-BE_current.accdb'. To download the client software, visit the following site: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=285987."}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"DataSource.NotFound"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: Acquisition_Overview.
Cluster-URIWABI-NORTH-EUROPE-L-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Aktivitäts-IDb5924bb8-a673-4ebd-8dc5-94d8d4af6b02
Anforderungs-IDd4f1083a-dfd5-3c96-dfca-4ecca3a57eb1
Zeit2021-11-18 10:03:07Z
```

Does someone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/accessdatabase

Comment: Does that mean, that the report server needs an extra Access Engine next to the Access programm to be installed? But why does the upload of the database and everything else works fine except for the refresh on the cloud and the report server? Is this Access Engine like a extra Access Programm just for Power BI?

Comment: All the PowerBI Desktop connectors don't support cloud refresh. You might need a gateway for few of the connectors.

Comment: The gateway is existing. We activated the gateway uploaded it with it but just the refresh is not working.

Comment: The bit that matters in your error message is _The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine OLEDB provider may be required_ Perhaps you need to install this driver on the gateway machine.

Comment: since we are not allowed to install packages online and our company does not have the necessery access engine...is there maybe a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following on-premise data sources can NOT be used with Power BI Cloud

- SAP BW
- SAP HANA
- ODBC
- Access DB / Legacy Excel files (.xls)

This means that Access DB cannot be refreshed in the Power BI Cloud.